# Here Maps {"error":"Unauthorized","error_description":"ApiKey invalid. ApiKey not found."} Documentation Error

Tags: api, here-api, unauthorizedaccessexcepti, here-maps-rest, keynotfoundexception

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/routing.html

```
{"error":"Unauthorized","error_description":"ApiKey invalid. ApiKey not found."}
```

I am using here maps api for routing and it's showing api key error key not found when i am passing key parameter in json format

```
// Instantiate a map and platform object:
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  'apikey': '{YOUR_APIKEY}'
});
```

The maps is working find when  i pass the key as simple string i don't know if there is any error in documentation or at the api please update this on your site and check it once

the working code is below:

// Instantiate a map and platform object:

```
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  'apikey': 'YOUR_APIKEY'
});
```

just remove "{}" and it is working find

Answer (score 1):

you should take your request and paste it on google search (the webpage search top bar). Remove any questionmark in the end, and you will see it will work, and will re-format the request. Copy the request from Google and try it on Postman now; hopefully it will work...
It worked for me.